# Data wrangling to add columns that sum up counts of mapped values R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of counts per person that looks like this:

```
Person_ID Apple Pear Chicken Steak Spinach
   1        1    0      0      5      1
   2        1    1      1      0      0
   3        0    0      0      3      2
```

I have another dataframe that maps which food belongs to which food group and looks like this:

```
Food     Group
Apple    Fruit
Pear     Fruit
Chicken  Meat
Steak    Meat
Spinach  Vegetable
```

I want to use the 2nd dataframe to add new columns on the 1st, basically creating new columns representing the food groups and collecting the counts based on the sum of their constituent columns, so that the final output looks like this:

```
Person_ID Apple Pear Chicken Steak Spinach Fruit Meat Vegetable
   1        1    0      0      5      1      1    5       1
   2        1    1      1      0      0      2    1       0
   3        0    0      0      3      2      0    3       2
```

I am having trouble doing this in a clean way, and it seems quite complicated. I am wondering if there is a simple solution, and would appreciate advice on any solution at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just need assignment i.e. select the subset of columns of 'df1' with 'Food' column of 'df2', `split` those with 'Group' column into a `list`, get the `rowSums` and assign those to create new columns in 'df1' based on the 'Group' column values

```
m1 <- sapply(split.default(df1[df2$Food], df2$Group), rowSums)
df1[colnames(m1)] <- m1
```

-ouptut

```
df1
  Person_ID Apple Pear Chicken Steak Spinach Fruit Meat Vegetable
1         1     1    0       0     5       1     1    5         1
2         2     1    1       1     0       0     2    1         0
3         3     0    0       0     3       2     0    3         2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Person_ID = 1:3, Apple = c(1L, 1L, 0L), Pear = c(0L, 
1L, 0L), Chicken = c(0L, 1L, 0L), Steak = c(5L, 0L, 3L), Spinach = c(1L, 
0L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Food = c("Apple", "Pear", "Chicken", "Steak", 
"Spinach"), Group = c("Fruit", "Fruit", "Meat", "Meat", "Vegetable"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: This is truly elegant! If I'm not mistaken we don't have an equivalent to `split.default` in tidyverse.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR thanks, there should be something similar in `group_split` i.e. `group_split.default` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df1 %>%
              pivot_longer(!Person_ID, names_to = "Food") %>%
              left_join(df2, by = "Food") %>%
              group_by(Person_ID, Group) %>%
              summarise(sum = sum(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
              pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = sum), by = "Person_ID")

  Person_ID Apple Pear Chicken Steak Spinach Fruit Meat Vegetable
1         1     1    0       0     5       1     1    5         1
2         2     1    1       1     0       0     2    1         0
3         3     0    0       0     3       2     0    3         2
```

Comment: Why not map? :-)

Comment: Haha yeah I tried a bit with `pamp` yesterday but thought it would only get more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `purrr::reduce` here

```r
library(tidyverse)

reduce(unique(df2$Group), 
       .init = df1,
       ~ .x %>% 
         mutate(!!.y := rowSums(df1[names(df1) %in% df2$Food[df2$Group == .y]]))
       )

#>   Person_ID Apple Pear Chicken Steak Spinach Fruit Meat Vegetable
#> 1         1     1    0       0     5       1     1    5         1
#> 2         2     1    1       1     0       0     2    1         0
#> 3         3     0    0       0     3       2     0    3         2
```

---

Or equivalently in baseR

```
Reduce(function(x, y) {x[[y]] <- rowSums(x[names(df1) %in% df2$Food[df2$Group == y]])
  x}, init = df1, unique(df2$Group))

  Person_ID Apple Pear Chicken Steak Spinach Fruit Meat Vegetable
1         1     1    0       0     5       1     1    5         1
2         2     1    1       1     0       0     2    1         0
3         3     0    0       0     3       2     0    3         2
```

Comment: Fantabulous and artful!